# JSON Web Token Implementation: access and refresh token

Tags: api, authentication, jwt, json-web-token

I am about to implement an authentication system that uses the JSON Web Token(JWT) approach. I read online multiple approaches taken but they seem to always be slightly different than the on I'm thinking on using.

The approach I am thinking of is:

- A user logs in causing the server to create a refresh token and an access token. (The Refresh token consists of an id and an expiry date, and the access token is a JWT valid for 15 minutes that contains the refresh token id)
- The user can make several successful requests using the access token until it expires
- Once the user does a request with an expired token, the server checks if the refresh token id contained within the expired access token matches the current refresh token
- If it matches, change the refresh token id and create a new access token containing the new refresh token id
- If it doesn't match, ask for authentication

I believe that this approach has the following advantages:

- it doesn't require the client to deal with the refresh token directly
- a DB or cache request has to be done only once every 15 minutes to check on the refresh token
- it allows the application to terminate a session by removing the refresh token from the DB or cache.
- the server will create only one access token that matches a refresh token. Once the access token is renewed, using it again will not cause another refresh action

Could anyone comment on this? Is this a good approach?

Comment: I think you question is on-topic

Answer (score 1):

The objective of refresh tokens is allow applications to obtain a new access token without re-authenticate minimizing the effect of a stolen token. If you allow to renew automatically including a refresh ID in the token itself, you are in fact extending the lifetime of the token without deliberately requiring the refresh token

An attacker who stoles a JWT could indefinitely impersonate user until the user performs a new access and ID does not match.

I think it is more secure to obtain a new access token before it expire using specifically the refresh token

Comment: So what do you recommend to do? Create both tokens, provide both tokens to the user, hope that the user will always use the access one and once it expires ask him to provide to refresh token?

Comment: You can provide the refresh token and issue access tokens when needed. For example issue an access token after an user action and if it is expired because user is inactivo, require the refresh token ( or credentials depending on your needs)Take a look at https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/. Also you can issue access token after fixed period of time